# Division of very large numbers in python 3

Tags: python

```
l=map(int, input().split())
print(int(sum(l)/2))
```

This program will take 3 integer inputs from the console, add them up and divide that number by 2, then print out the integral part. For small numbers, this program works fine. However, if the input is `9547116602436426 8316250877914575 2981260158260522` then the program prints `10422313819305762`. The expected answer was `10422313819305761`. Does python 3 mess up with really big numbers? Does it need a new data type as in C? Or is there something wrong in my code?
Note: I am absolutely new to python, but have some moderate idea about C programming language.

Comment: because you are calling `int` on a `float`: `int(sum(l)/2)` so it will truncate.

Comment: You are taking the integer part, which rounds positive numbers down.

Comment: Sorry, I missed something. The program would print only the integral part

Comment: Are you looking for integer division `//`? This gives the "correct" result, but note that the result is not really correct since the sum is odd and thus the result should be somethin ´.5`

Comment: @tobias_k yeah! Exactly what I was looking for. This was a contest programming problem. I needed only the integral part.

Comment: @user148469 Usually, your `int(...)` should do the same, but if the numbers are very large, the intermediate floating point number can lead to precision loss.